# Download text from a txt file in Dropbox

Tags: java, android

I have a .txt file uploaded to the Public folder in Dropbox. If you click on the file, it opens and you can see the text, and if you check the HTML source code, it only shows the text that is inside the file (no HTML tags, just string). Is there a way to download that text to a String variable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029042/read-data-from-a-txt-file-without-downloading-it?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First open the file via HttpUrlConnection.
- Then read the file in a buffer.
- Just do `buffer.toString();`

And here's the code:

```
URL url = new URL("Link to dropbox");
                HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.setDoOutput(false);
                con.setReadTimeout(20000);
                con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");

                con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0");
                ((HttpURLConnection) con).setRequestMethod("GET");
                //System.out.println(con.getContentLength()) ;
                con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    System.out.println(responseCode);
                }
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                int chars_read;
                //int total = 0;
                while ((chars_read = in.read()) != -1) 
                {
                    char g = (char) chars_read;
                    buffer.append(g);
                }
                final String page = buffer.toString();
```

Put all this in a new thread, and a try-catch block.

Comment: I'm trying to display "page", but nothing happens.

Comment: set up a break point on page and debug, the code written above is correct. And make your questions more detailed, "nothing happens" does not explain anything.
Read FAQs on stack overflow about asking better questions.

Comment: What happens is that when I click on the button that starts the new thread, a debugger view shows up that says "source not found". I've put internet permission to the manifest.

Comment: I've got it working now, but it doesn't work with dropbox links, only with regular URI's (www.google.com).

Comment: Another question: how do I change the encoding? Because some characters are not being read right.

Comment: Your dropbox link may not be valid, make sure you put it in public folder. and for the encoding, ihave never had this problem but you can try this header .........Con.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8;");..............

Comment: Still doesn't show the right characters. I'm trying to display "č, ž, Š", but it shows some other characters. I've also tried changing "charset" to Cp1250, but it still doesn't work.